# Runtime error in finding prime numbers

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Spoj problem-
http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

There is a logical error in the code and is not running.

**IDE**-Codeblocks

```
int main()
{
    int t,*prime;
    long long int m,n,i,j;
    //t for number of test cases

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%llu%llu",&m,&n);
        prime=(int*)(malloc((n-m)*sizeof(int)));

        //Initialising all elements as 1 
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            prime[i]=1;
        }

        prime[0]=0;
        prime[1]=0;

        //Initialising all the multiples of primes as 0 as in sieve algorithm
        for(i=m;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(prime[i]!=0){
                for(j=2;j*i<=1000000000;j++)
                {
                    prime[j*i]=0;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=m;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%llu\n",i);
        }

        free(prime);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question! The button is labelled `Ask Question` for a reason. Also, your problem description is very poor. What is the logical error exactly? How are you trying to run the code and what exactly happens when you try? What happens when you try to debug the code?

Comment: It doesn't run but it shows no error on compiling

Comment: "It doesn't run" is not a helpful problem description. How are you trying to run it? What happens when you try? What happens when you run it in a debugger? How far have you traced its operation? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: So it doesn't even ask for input?

Comment: Well I don't know how to use debugger but the program is crashing on running it.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger. So compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: always check the returned value from the scanf() function to assure all input/conversions were successful.  This line: 'scanf("%llu%llu",&m,&n);'  has a problem.  How is scanf to tell when one number ends and the next begins?  suggest: 'scanf("%llu %llu",&m,&n);'  how is the user to know what to enter when there is not prompt indicating what is expected?

Comment: regarding this line: 'prime=(int*)(malloc((n-m)*sizeof(int)));' 1) do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family). 2) check that 'n' is greater than 'm' otherwise this is asking for a HUGE amount of memory.  3) always check the returned value from malloc 9and family) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the problem has plenty of description.. That description should be appropriately displayed to the user.  The problem states to input 'number of test cases'  then input 2 numbers ,followed by a newline, for each test case,  then output any prime numbers within the range of each test case, where each successive test case is separated from its' neighbors by a blank line.   That is NOT what the posted code is doing.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on stackoverflow on how to generate prime numbers.  the OP should use one of them for generating the primes. and for each generated prime, only output it if it is in the range n...m.

Comment: the first thing to use the debugger (after getting an executable that compiles/links with no errors/warnings, is 1) gdb executableName 2) br main 3) run  This will get the execution to the beginning of the main() function.  then use such statements as 's(tep)' 'n(ext)' 'p(rint) varname' 'l(ist)' 'q(uit)'  here is a link to a gdb tutorial: <http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_toc.html>  (there are other tutorials available, use google to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%lld %lld",&m,&n);
prime=(int*)(malloc((n-m)*sizeof(int)))
```

You are allocating memory for `n-m` elements and you are trying to access the `m`th to `n-1` th element which is out of bound access which will lead to undefined behavior hence you are seeing a crash.

There are similar other access in the same loop so you should take care of this.

For example:

The input is 5 and 10 i.e `m=5` and `n=10` ( Format specifier should be `%lld` for long long)

Now the memory allocated is for 5 elements `prime[0]` to `prime[4]` .

In the for loop you have access like `i<n` In this case you will have access like

`prime[9]` which will cause crash because you are accessing some memory which is not allocated by you

The other access has

`prime[j*i]` What if i=3 and j=4

You are accessing `prime[12]`

Comment: Not to mention `prime[j*i]=0;`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes sir.. I poined out the loop in which the OP has mentioned there is a crash ..

Comment: Even after removing it is crashing

Comment: Okay so I should avoid using dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Beginner Not actually you can use dynamic allocation but make sure you handle it properly

Comment: I have used this  prime=    (int*)(malloc((n*m)*sizeof(int)));
but still its giving false output.